# Select points with maximum attribute value per category on a spatial join with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I'm trying to select the points with the maximum altitude value contained in the polygons of a grid. grid and point with altitude

[image: grid and points]

I've managed to get the max value per category:

```
SELECT grid.pagename, max(pnt.altitude) AS max_altitude
FROM grid_150m as grid LEFT JOIN pnt_cote_index_proj as pnt 
ON st_contains(grid.geom, pnt.geom) 
GROUP BY grid.pagename
```

The hard part is to get the actual geometry, without success I've tried:

```
SELECT distinct on (pnt.altitude) pnt.altitude, grid.pagename, pnt.geom
FROM grid_150m as grid 
LEFT JOIN pnt_cote_index_proj as pnt 
ON st_contains(grid.geom, pnt.geom) 
group by grid.pagename, pnt.altitude, pnt.geom
order by pnt.altitude;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1 (of X) - LATERAL:**

Since it´s implementation (and, at least, with the spatial component), I´d say the [`JOIN LATERAL`](https://medium.com/kkempin/postgresqls-lateral-join-bfd6bd0199df) is the ultimate tool for this [*]:

```
SELECT grid.pagename,
       point.altitude,
       point.geom
FROM grid_150m AS grid
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT altitude,
         geom
  FROM pnt_cote_index_proj AS pt
  WHERE grid.geom && pt.geom
  ORDER BY altitude DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS point
ON true;
```

The right hand subquery will select the first point's `geom` and `altitude` in descending order of `altitude`of all contained points per grid for each row in the grid layer.
Use `...OFFSET <rank>;` after the `LIMIT 1` to select e.g. the 2nd highest value.
The `&&` operator makes efficient use of the spatial indexes (in theory, there should be no intersections with multiple grid bboxes...but if in doubt, change to `ST_Contains`).

[*]: The `LATERAL` join type is glorious! Another very interesting purpose in terms of spatial analysis is it´s use for *(K) Nearest Neighbor* (*KNN*) searches. If of interest, there are multiple related post on this board.

Comment: The lateral join is indeed glorious, as are window functions.

Answer (score 0):

*Since no one joined in yet, I´ll pick up the ranking option I mentioned and add another answer.*
**Option 2 (of X) - ranking subquery:**
This one is another common approach, using PostgreSQL's [ranking window functions](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/).

This is the (possibly significantly) slower one compared to a `JOIN LATERAL`, but it has two major advantages:

- if there happens to be multiple points with the same altitude, this
  will select all of them
- you can select the rank you want pretty straight forward, e.g. the 2nd highest value, by changing
   `... WHERE rnk = <rank>;`

With

```
SELECT ranked.pagename,
       ranked.altitude,
       ranked.geom
FROM (
    SELECT grid.pagename,
           point.altitude,
           point.geom
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY grid.pagename ORDER BY point.altitude DESC) AS rnk
    FROM grid_150m AS py
    LEFT JOIN pnt_cote_index_proj AS pt
      ON grid.geom && pt.geom
) AS ranked
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

the `DENSE_RANK()`function will assign a rank based on the descending order of `altitudes` for each partitioned `pagename` window, with the same rank for same `altitude` values.
Same rules as in the other answer for the `&&` operator.

Comment: This option takes twice longer (not a worry to wait 500ms against 250ms). The rank option could be really useful but in my case I was searching for one value per bbox.